# Manhwa (most likely) or manga about a boy who ends up in a survival game after receiving money for a relative's medical expenses and a bracelet

Tags: story-identification, manga

Been trying to find its name for quite a while.

There might be some incorrect details. Used (?) where wasn't sure.

Protagonist (15-17 y.o.) had problems with money (for the treatment of a relative(?)). Some shady guy (in a mask(?)) told him that he could help solve this problem by doing the task that he would give him. The task was to run to some place in the city before this guy. Protagonist barely made it. That person gave him money and a bracelet(?) saying that if he wants more money he can activate it (sort of). And after activation, protagonist found himself in some big room with a bunch of people in confusion, who began to think about how to get out of there until they were told something from the loudspeakers (about the game of survival).

The game consisted of going into rooms in which strange monsters were waiting, and one could also choose the difficulty. After clearing rooms people were given points (according to difficulty) that could be used to buy food, weapons and pay for accommodation (each day cost 100(?) points). If the points ran out, the person was killed. The hero’s ability was associated either with slowing down time, or with the ability to rewind it a little. As far as I remember, the first room was a room with a dwarf-like creature with a knife on easy difficulty. On medium it was the same creature, but the room had pools with acid an narrow passages, and on the last difficulty there were two of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it myself after like 10 more hours of struggling.

It's called ***[I'm Unrivalled in the Mystery Game](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/tm0w1wf/chicheng-zai-yanmie-bianyuan)*** and it was frozen after the first season (25 chapters). :(

> The temporary worker Yu Xiaobei entered a mysterious arena in order to pay for his sister's high surgery expenses, only to learn that the reward for surviving till the end was ownership of the top financial group in the world, which was the leader of the global economy. Unexpectedly, he was not the only player. In the face of deceit and terrifying monsters, Yu Xiaobei participates in round after round of thrilling death games. To his secret delight, an unexpected gift shows the protagonist that his goal is not out of reach!

Comment: Glad you found it. We'd be grateful if you'd mark your answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons on the left side of the answer. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction. However, as this is a self-answer, you'll need to wait until 48 hours after the question was first posted before the site will let you do that.